# Can you conditionally compile something in Rust based on whether the target pointer width is at least some value?

Tags: rust

I’m working on a trait that includes a function measuring property about the type. The return type is `Option<usize>` to allow for values larger than `usize::MAX`, but I included an overrideable function that returns just `usize` and panics otherwise that is, by default, implemented via the safe function. I now want to implement this trait for numeric types already in Rust. I want to override the panicking function for types that are contained within `usize` with a faster implementation.

How can I conditionally compile a trait function based on whether or not a given numeric type is wholly contained within `usize`? I’ve looked at `target_pointer_width` but this is not forward-compatible as I’d have to list of all pointer widths that I currently expect to exist and have that property manually. Is there some way to do it automatically? Ideally there’d be a `#[cfg(target_pointer_width >= "64")]` or something but there isn’t.

Comment: I don't expect there will be any pointer width greater than 64 bits in the next few decades. 64 bit pointers ought to be enough for anyone.

Comment: @SvenMarnach there are some experimental architectures where the pointer address also encodes provenance information, and packs the whole thing into 128 bits. It's not completely clear to me how this would translate into Rust, but I _think_ the `usize` would be 128 bit and `isize` would still be 64 bit.

Comment: @PeterHall I believe the plan is that pointers (`*const T` and `*mut T`) would be 128 bits, but `usize` and `isize` would be 64 bits.

Comment: If you just delegate to the various underlying implementations from a `match usize::BITS`, won't rust elide that at compile time since it's const evaluable ?

Comment: That doesn’t allow me to conditionally implement a trait, which I was also looking for, but yes, that does solve my original problem! You could write an answer containing that so I can accept it.

Comment: I have hard time believing the optimizer will not remove those unreachable panics anyway.